# How to move GIMP to another virtual desktop?

Tags: kde, gimp, virtual-desktop

When I need GIMP to open in another virtual desktop, I must switch the desktop just after opening GIMP, before it loads. Otherwise I am not able to move all its dialogs, only the main window. Is there a way to easily move all GIMP windows and dialogs at once to another virtual desktop in KDE? (I had the same problem in other DEs, too).

Comment: You could use [`xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html)

Comment: What version of GIMP are you using?

Comment: This has been a problem for years, with all GIMP versions without exception.